# Wordpress Site Domain Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site `www.xyz.com`. when i typed `www.xyz.com` in the address bar of the browser it is getting redirected to `xyz.com` without `www`. 
I even tried to redirect the domain url to `www.xyz.com` in `.htaccess` file. but it is generating an error as indefinite loop.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

That is really easy to fix, just go to the admin part, in settings/general and add www to the site and home url's  name!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is due to permalink setting in you Wordpress installation.

Make sure to change these 2 URLs in your permalink setting:

1. Site URL
2. Home URL

To make sure both of them start with `http://www.xyz.com`

Answer (score 0):

There are two places to check, first log into the wordpress install and go to general settings, and change the following entries:

```
WordPress Address (URL)
Site Address (URL)
```

If the textboxs are grey, then SFTP into your server and edit the `wp-config.php` file. Look for the following lines in it, and add `www.` in front of the domain.

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://domain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://domain.com');
```

P.S. it won't say domain, it'll have your domain there.

Comment: them if it is like that, is better to do it the right way and add `update_option('siteurl','http://example.com');
update_option('home','http://example.com');` so it is the right color in the wordpress interface ;)

Comment: @jycr753 I'm not sure I follow, by using `define` wordpress skips the database look up.

Comment: I know mate, but i think is better, in the case that he cant change it directly in worpdress, to set the settings properly. dont you think? this way the moved, copied site has the right settings